# Remove empty object from json array using GSON

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, gson

```
{
  "ChangeRequests": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

Remove the empty model from JSON array using Gson. 
Because of it create the one model inside the list in the model all value is null using Gson

```
data class TestRequest(
@SerializedName("ChangeRequests")
val changeRequests: List<ChangeRequest>
```

)

```
val result = Gson().fromJson(jsonString,TestRequest::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

simple code : it worked for me !

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);

for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = data.entrySet().iterator(); 
it.hasNext();) {
Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
if (entry.getValue() == null) {
    it.remove();
} else if (entry.getValue().getClass().equals(ArrayList.class)) {
    if (((ArrayList<?>) entry.getValue()).size() == 0) {
        it.remove();
    }
 }
}

String json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data);
System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: This you are processing after converting JSON into a model. I want is it something at GsonBuilder level.